# How to insert reference values in database using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

I am trying to insert values into Oracle 10g database using the code below but its giving an error of "Missing Expression" on execution. I have to pass reference values into the insert clause but do not know the exact syntax or way of doing it. 
Please help me through this.
Thanks.

**Student Table:-**

```
                      Sid       VARCHAR2(200) PRIMARY KEY  CHECK(Sid>0),
                      Pass_word VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                      S_name    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
                      G_name    VARCHAR2(20)         ,
                      Branch    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                      D_company VARCHAR2(20)         ,
                      B_Percent INT NOT NULL CHECK(B_Percent<100),
                      twelth_percent INT NOT NULL CHECK(twelth_percent<100),
                      tenth_percent INT NOT NULL  CHECK(tenth_percent<100),
                      Certify   VARCHAR2(30),
                      Semester  INT NOT NULL CHECK(Semester<9),
                      D_Birth   DATE NOT NULL,
                      Sex       VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL
```

**CODE:**

```
Connection connection = null;

try
{

  // Load the JDBC driver

   String driverName = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

   Class.forName(driverName);

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:placement","siddharth","sid");

    studentID = StudentID.getText();
    spassword = PasswordField.getPassword();
    studentname = NameField.getText();
    Gname = GuardianField.getText();
    branch = BranchField.getText();
    dcompany = DcompanyField.getText();
    bpercent = BtechField1.getText();
    twelthpercent = TwelthField.getText();
    tenthpercent = TenthField.getText();
    semester = SemesterField.getText();
    certify = CertificationField.getText();
    sex = SexCombo.getActionCommand();
    date =  (Date) DateTextField1.getValue();



    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into student " +"(sid,pass_word,s_name,g_name,branch,d_company,b_percent,twelth_percent,tenth_percent,certify,semester,d_birth,sex)"+
                 "values(studentID, spassword,studentname,Gname,branch,dcompany,bpercent,twelthpercent,tenthpercent,certify,semester,date,sex)" );

    stmt.close();
    connection.close();
    }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Could not find the database driver
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
    // Could not connect to the database
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently your SQL statement looks like:

```
insert into student (sid, pass_word, ...) values (studentID, spassword, ...)
```

The variable names mean nothing to the SQL itself.

You should use a *prepared statement*. For example, your SQL should look like this:

```
insert into student (sid, pass_word, ...) values (?, ?, ...)
```

and then you use:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, studentID);
stmt.setString(2, spassword);

// etc
```

See the [JDBC tutorial on prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information.

Comment: PreparedStatement state=connection.prepareStatement(sql);                               "sql" here is giving error. What exactly is needed to be written in place of "sql"??

Comment: @Siddharth: That's the text of the SQL statement.

Comment: Hey thanx a ton Jon :)  Are you present on facebook or any social networking site?

Comment: @Jon - I am trying to insert a date into my database but I am not sure what to to use here. Help me out.                               I have tried state.setDate(13,date); but this is giving error.

Comment: @Siddharth: Please post a separate question with a *short* but complete program (or at least self-contained snippet) demonstrating the problem (i.e. *only* inserting a date). Include the details of the error - read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side you should use prepared statements.

Prepare the Query String

```
String updateString = "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
                      "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
```

Create a PrepartedStatement with this query:

```
updateSales = connnection.prepareStatement(updateString);
```

Fill the ? spaceholders with you values:

```
updateSales.setInt(1, myVariable1);
updateSales.setString(2, myVariable2);
```

execute the Query

```
updateSales.executeUpdate();
```